# Why do we use "make" command when "cc ex1.c -o ex1" compiles the code written in "exe1.c" file

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, makefile, compilation

I was learning C programming in Linux while I came across this line of code

```
$ make ex1

cc ex1.c -o ex1
```

My question is why do we have to use `make ex1`?  Isn't the `cc` command building the program and other necessary files.

Comment: Please suggest where am I lacking in programming. I had studied from my curriculum books where there is no mention about these things where can I get detailed knowledge about this .

Comment: You *do not* need to use `make` to build your programs.  It is a convenience.  For simple one-source programs such as you demonstrate, the convenience is minor, but for most real-world programs and libraries, the convenience is compelling.

Answer (score 3):

With the exception of small set of very simple problem, almost all real-life C programs will be built from multiple modules, header files, external libraries, sometimes spanning over multiple folders. In some cases, additional code may be linked in using different tools (e.g., code generators).

For those cases, single 'cc' command is not going to work. The next solution will be to automated the build using build script. However, this can be time consuming to build, and almost impossible to maintain.

For building "C" programs, Make provides the many benefits on top of a simple shell build script. This is my personal "top 3"

- Incremental build - when code files are modified, make can identify the execute the minimal set of build instructions, instead of rebuilding the whole code. This can provide a major efficiency boost to developers.
- Rule based build - make uses rules to produce targets. Once you define a rule (one obvious rule: compile a ".c" file to ".o"), they can be applied consistently on all files.
- provides setup for complete build process - including installation of code, cleanup, packaging, test, etc. Very important is that make can integrate (almost) any Unix tool into the build process - code generation, etc.

Needless to say, there are other build tools which provide additional/alternate benefits. CMake, gradle, SCons, to name a few.

Answer (score 1):

For a one-file project, they come out to about the same. However, real-world projects tend to have tens, hundreds, or thousands of files and build tens or hundreds of libraries and executables, possibly with different settings etc. Managing all of this without storing the compilation commands somewhere would be impossible, and a Makefile is a very useful "somewhere."

Another important property of make is that it does timestamp checks on files and only re-runs the compilation/linking commands whose outputs are outdated, i.e. at least one of their inputs is newer than the outputs. Without such checks, you'd have to manually remember which files to recompile when you change something (especially difficult when the changed file is a header), or always recompile everything, increasing build times by orders of magnitude.